# I have got this code to remove the last element of a list. How can i change this to remove a set word regardless of its location?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
#lang racket
(define (remove-last lst)
    (if (null? (cdr lst))
        '()
        (cons (car lst) (remove-last (cdr lst)))))

(remove-last '(Help Me Please))
```

This then prints out:

`(Help Me)`

How can I change this? For example if I wanted to remove `me`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question -- looks like homework

Comment: I now have this code from previous help

Comment: @NormanGray Homework is not considered off-topic on SO.

Comment: @uselpa Indeed (cf [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/)). But this is off-topic because it's too vague, and lacks evidence of research (the underlying reason for that is because it's probably homework, but it's the off-topic-ness that gets it the close-vote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
(define (remove-words lst words)
  (cond 
    ((null? lst) 
     '())
    ((member (car lst) words) 
     (remove-words (cdr lst) words))
    (else 
     (cons (car lst) (remove-words (cdr lst) words)))))
```

then

```
> (remove-words '(Help Me Please) '(Me Help Not))
'(Please)
```

You can also use the procedures for sets:

```
(define (remove-words lst words)
  (set-subtract lst words))
```

Please note that you are working with symbols here, not strings.

Comment: Thats Great! Is there a way for the user to type the word they want removed? So for example in my java equivalent I have used this:

String[] RemoveWords = new String[]{"times”, "age", "epoch”, "the", "it"};

Which allows the user to choose which words are removed from a string.

Comment: Dear down-voter, please feel free to openly share your criticism about my answer. I don't care about the points, but I do care about feedback and insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve the problem using [`filter-not`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._filter-not%29%29) and `member` together:

```
(define (remove-words lst words)
  (filter-not (lambda (x) (member x words) lst))
```

If you want to cut down on the wordiness of that anonymous function, the tools most suited to that are [`curry`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=curry&q=cut#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29) and [`cut`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-26.html?q=cut#cut)  (with the latter needing a `(require srfi/26)` to use).

Currying a function turns it into a new function that accepts one argument, then returns another function that accepts one more argument, then again, then again, and so on until it has all the arguments it needs to call the original function. A curried version of `remove-words` would be called as `((remove-words lst) words)` instead, and you could make it from our current implementation with `(curry remove-words)`. This requires that the arguments be supplied in left to right order, which doesn't work for `member`. There's another form `curryr` that goes right-to-left, but because `member` takes an optional third argument it won't work.

You could use [`cut`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-26.html?q=cut#cut) (from srfi 26) then, which lets you pick which arguments of a function you want to "lock-in" and which you want the new function to accept. `(cut member <> words)`creates a new function `(lambda (arg) (member arg words))` and `(cut * <> <> 8)` creates `(lambda (arg1 arg2) (* arg1 arg2 8))`. So with this, `remove-words` looks like:

```
(require srfi/26)
(define (remove-words lst words)
  (filter-not (cut member <> words) lst))
```

Although going with `set-subtract` is still probably the best solution since you should avoid reinventing the wheel as much as possible (unless you're trying to learn more about wheels). Nonetheless, it's very useful to have a firm grip on the general functions provided by Racket that make your life easier.